When does a line no longer approximate an exponential curve sufficiently well?
I have a somewhat complicated question and as someone with no data analysis or strong statistical science background, I'm searching for advice/recommendations for the best data analysis "tool" or method to do what I need.
For context, I am analyzing a phenomenon in the aurora that brightens exponentially with time. I am manually selecting events and eyeballing initial and final times to extract my brightness values (-axis here). I am using ground-based imagers and extracting brightness values from an average number of pixels. I have a number of events, currently 13 which I am plotting below.
My goal is to find the growth rate of the brightness which is important for picking out the exact plasma instability responsible for this specific type of aurora. To do this, I have to only calculate the growth rate based on the linear phase of the plasma instability. In other words, when plotting log-linear, you would only see a straight line in the linear phase and when that line starts deviating, that would signify the nonlinear phase and not the same auroral phenomenon anymore. The nonlinear phase can either be a more rapid brightening of the aurora, or the aurora could start to fade away.
What I have set up now is a code that puts all the curves for all the events, plots in log-linear, and calculates a line of best fit for every point after two points then after the line of best fit goes out of tolerance (i.e., below $r^2$=0.85), that next point is labeled as non-linear.
This sounds great, except that in some events, the brightness goes down for the first few time steps because I am selecting pixels in the aurora image that are getting slightly darker before the event takes place (i.e., I was sloppy at choosing my start time ($t_0$ for the event).
Is there some kind of boxcar averaging method I can use to make sure this doesn't happen, or should I apply a Gaussian filter to the data (although there aren't many data points in the time series) and then perform analysis on those smoothed points?
I am also going to background-subtract all the events so that they are normalized to 0.1 as the background value (taking the smallest brightness in the time series as the background) to make the plots a bit nicer to look at.
All events plotted linear-linear. Brightness vs. time. The linear phase is in blue, dotted green line shows the transition, and then red lines are nonlinear growth.



Can you formulate a parametric model for the entire curve, including the saturation effect at the end? If yes, you can estimate the model parameters (e.g. by least-squares) and compute the "breakpoint" therefrom. Would you mind providing the data points of the last plot with dput?

Not sure how to do it with dput, so here are the values for the imager counts (brightness): 3620.00, 3788.00, 4078.33, 4356.67, 4821.00, 6307.33, 6482.67, 7846.67, 9890.67, 13280.0, 19387.3, 14435.7, 22697.7, 25539.3, 23001.3, 20703.3, 25667.3, 23548.0, 23696.0, 19236.0, 18373.3, 24011.0, 20592.7, 26886.7, 25767.3, 27628.3

dput(data_frame_name) in R

A side point: I think your title is a little misleading and would recommend editing it to reflect the core of your question.


One solution is to use a piecewise regression. If the beginning and end of each time series should be reasonably flat, you can estimate two breakpoints separating three lines: a line with zero slope, a line with positive slope, and then another line with zero slope again. This exact approach is explained here: Piecewise regression with constraints . If those zero-slope constraints do not make sense, a simple piecewise regression that allows all slopes to vary freely would work better. If it is uncertain whether the initial portion should be increasing (i.e. exponential) or not, then one can also fit a model with one less breakpoint and compare the two models with some sort of criterion such as AICc / BIC.

A second solution would be to fit a 4-parameter logistic function to each time series. This makes some strong assumptions about the shape and so it may not work well in every case.


Both of these would probably be simpler to fit if there is no decrease in the response value (brightness) towards the end of the time series. If there is, you would want to either make the model more complex, allow the slope of the final line of the piecewise regression to have a non-zero value, or simply exclude the end of the time series (though this should be done with caution, as it has the potential to introduce bias).

The correct way should be to built an equation model based on the physical properties. If this isn't possible one have to empirically find a purely mathematical equation model without expecting physical signifiance of the parameters. Unfortunately that is what we have to do considering how the  question is raised.
A first difficulty is the large scatter of the points on the given graphs. It is difficult to guess what is the real shape of the curves. So one cannot a priori infer the kind of function to use.
This draw us to check many functions and see if one of them is satisfying.
On can introduce into the equation model various functions such as polynomial or logistic or gaussian or etc.
A second difficulty is the lack of data. There was no data in the original question but only graphs. Latter a data was given in comments but only for one case (corresponding to the second graph in the question).
On the first graph in the question it seems that they are ten curves. Without the data corresponding to those ten cases one cannot check if a "guessed" equation model built from only one curve is convenient for all (Of course with different adjustments of the parameters to each case).
In order to illustrate the empirical method only an example of mathematical model is shown below. The equation model is certainly not the best.

